# Getting slow internet speed on Netgear jwnr2000v2

Tags: router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I am using Netgear jwnr2000v2.

Below is config

2.4ghz and protocol is b/g/n and my router is on auto channel.

The fibre line from my isp gives 50 mbps. But my wifi router gives only 20 mbps and not more.  I tried to search settings in my router manual but couldn't find the option for it.

Also the way I got to know that fibre line from my isp gives 50 mbps is when I connected my system directly with fibre line cable and then connected to my isp via 100mbps full duplex.

So I searched for this setting in my router but couldn't find it. Please help me.

Update

I found one link which basically explains my issue
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1930537/changing-auto-negotiation-100mbps-full-duplex-mode.html#r12186820

Comment: What computer/laptop are you using to test from?

Comment: Dell laptop and windows 8 os

Comment: What brand of Wireless NIC? Intel? And what are you connected via, 2.4GHz? 5GHz? a/b/g/n? Also what channel on the router?

Comment: I am connected on 2.4ghz and protocol is b/g/n and my router is on channel  1

Answer (score -1):

are you actually running speed test on the line? or is it just your connection speed that you are wanting (ie. the complete line speed) as your speed test results will be how fast you download not how fast your connection is to the ISP's network

Comment: i ran speedtest on ookla and it showed download close to 47 mbps